# Copying unique numbers from one column to the another

Tags: excel, formula, unique-values

I have a C column with the various 6-digit numbers "operator ID". Each operator is assigned to number of activities so their number will appear a couple of times in the C column. I need to extract the numbers of each operator into a separate column so I will know how many operators were involved in these activities. In the picture, I have 23 IDs but only 3 operators were involved.

[image]

What will be the formula to achieve this?

I was trying to use "Unique" but it gives me a copy of all the numbers.

Comment: share your formula so we know where went wrong. UNIQUE should do the job.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your usage of `UNIQUE()` function and what output it gave.

Comment: Share the data, one issue can be that what you think is a number has leading or trailing spaces or other hidden characters making IDs that should be the same unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have, for example 50 rows in your column with the numbers (let's suppose it's column "A"), you can select i.e. the first cell of a column next to your data and type:

=UNIQUE(A1:A50)

Now you will get the unique values you want, in this new column.